# Wordpress Apache RewriteRule

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I would like to redirect the Facebook crawlers to a static page, since my website is in AngularJS and I need to work with the og:meta. I'm using Wordpress as back-end, so at the moement this is my `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I tryed to add these two lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteRule tracks/(\d*)$ http://<path>/static.php [P]
```

But this is not working. If I try to scrape a page with the facebook tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) I'm not redirect to the static page.

Keep in mind that in wordpress my permalinks are build in this way: `http://<fqdn>/%category%/%postname%/` and `tracks/` is one of my category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to exclude the facebook crawler from the default 302 of wordpress.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !facebookexternalhit/1.1
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} facebookexternalhit/1.1
RewriteRule (.*) http://<dn>/static.php [L]
</IfModule>
```